# trying to implement quick sort using python but it's not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quicksort algorithm using python I think I have done the steps right but it seems like there's a problem with my code, everytime I run the code it doesn't work please can you help me find the problem with my code.

```
def quicksort(alist,first,last):
    if first < last:
        split = partition(alist,first,last)

        quicksort(alist,first,split-1)
        quicksort(alist,split+1,last)



def partition(arr,first,last):

    pivot_val = arr[first]
    rightmark = first +1
    leftmark = last

    done = False

    while not done:

        while leftmark <= rightmark and arr[leftmark] <= pivot_val:
            leftmark +=1
        while arr[rightmark] >= pivot_val and rightmark >= leftmark:
            rightmark -=1

        if rightmark < leftmark:
            done = True
        else:
            tmp = arr[leftmark]
            arr[leftmark] = arr[rightmark]
            arr[rightmark] = tmp


    tmp = arr[rightmark]
    arr[rightmark] = arr[first]
    arr[first] = tmp

    return rightmark


lst = [22,54,33,11,87,76,1,3]

quicksort(lst,0,len(lst)-1)

print(lst)
```

the output looks like this:

```
[54, 22, 11, 33, 76, 87, 1, 3]
```

Comment: quicksort(alist,first,split-1)
quicksort(alist,split+1,last)
what about split + 0?

Comment: @juvian I don't think the problem is here, I saw an Implementation close to this one and he did it just like this, I think the problem is somewhere in the **partition** function logic but I can't find where.

Comment: well, your code is very different from both pseudocodes in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: yeah it's a code snippet from a book called "problem solving with algorithms and data stractures using python". you can check it [here](https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheQuickSort.html) if you want they almost look indentical

Comment: _Almost_ identical, but left should be on the left of right, right? Double check your `leftmark` and `rightmark` initialization.

Comment: yes thank you I just realized how stupid I'm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the usual implementation has the pivot as the last value not the first but that is irrelevant. The error, however, is the initialization of rightmark and leftmark. Presuming leftmark is to the 'left' i.e. less than, and rightmark is greater than, then leftmark should be initialized to first+1 and rightmark should be initialized to last.

This is not the normal implementation of quicksort whose partition function simple loops linearly through the array (except for the pivot). This one cleverly moves the leftmark to the right until the first entry is greater than the pivot then moves the rightmark to the left until its first entry that is less than the pivot. Then it swaps these two values until they cross. That is the end condition.